# How to disable isVolumeFixed=true on Chrome OS?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, google-chrome-os, androidappsonchromeos

I'm making an app for Chrome OS that it's important to be able to adjust system volume with. It's not designed for the app store, but will be a side-loaded app.

However, while my Android Studio code to change volume works correctly on emulator and other devices, it doesn't have any effect on Chromebook. I notice that

```
audioManager.isVolumeFixed()
```

returns a value of `True`, which according to documentation is why `setStreamVolume` has no effect.

Is there any way to turn `volumeFixed` to `False`, either programmatically, through terminal commands, or in system settings? I looked at the device audio settings, but there doesn't seem to be any associated option...

Note that I already have developer mode enabled for the Chromebook in question.